# Why should not we call [super loadview] in loadView when creating a custom View controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Below is the information from Apple's developer [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW37). What do they mean " Doing so initiates the default view-loading behavior?

> When overriding the loadView method to create your views
>   programmatically, you should not call super. Doing so initiates the
>   default view-loading behavior and usually just wastes CPU cycles. Your
>   own implementation of the loadView method should do all the work that
>   is needed to create a root view and subviews for your view controller.
>   For more information on the view loading process, see “Understanding
>   How Views Are Loaded and Unloaded.”

Answer (score 7):

The "default behavior" is loading the XIB file of the same name, linking properties, etc. If there's no matching XIB file it will, as the documentation says, just waste CPU cycles.

Ultimately, without knowing how Apple have implemented the framework we *can't* know the reasoning behind all the recommendations in the documentation. But that doesn't mean you should ignore them...

Comment: A minor quibble: what actually gets loaded is a nib file rather than a xib file -- xib files are development artifacts, and aren't present at runtime.

Comment: I thought it was a simplification worth making for the sake of clarity, but, of course, you're right.

Comment: Wasn't trying to nitpick, but in teaching classes on iOS development I've noticed that kind of simplification sometimes backfires and actually causes more confusion in the long run.